# Safely rearrange folder structure for Heroku push

Tags: node.js, heroku

I need to fix my project's folder structure because when I currently `git push heroku main` Heroku can't find the `package.json` file to indicate it needs to use `node.js` buildpack.

Here is my current folder structure:

```
Recipes/
├─ recipes/
│  ├─ backend/
│  │  |
│  │  ├─ node_modules/
│  │  ├─ node_postgres/
│  │  │  ├─ node_modules/
│  │  │  ├─ index.js/
│  │  │  ├─ package-lock.json
│  │  │  ├─ package.json
│  ├─ frontend/
│  │  ├─ src/
│  │  ├─ public/
│  │  ├─ package-lock.json
│  │  ├─ README.md
│  │  ├─ package.json
```

How do I overcome this issue? Looks like I need to do some significant rearranging...

Comment: You either need to rearrange to move the server package file to the root directory, or _add_ a package file that proxies commands to the existing ones. Here's one I made earlier: https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit

Comment: Okay so would i just copy the server ``package.json`` to root? Will that not break things that call it in the ``node_postgres`` folder?

Comment: No, you don't just copy it. You'll actually have to refactor to account for that change. Or again and a third package file that proxies the appropriate commands.

Comment: Okay I'll see how your ``package.json`` is written and see if that helps guide me thanks